# How do I stop KDE from changing the alt-tab order of minimized windows?

Tags: kde-plasma

I'm on KDE Plasma 5.16.5 on Manjaro. When I use my keyboard shortcut to minimize a KDE window, I would like to be able to restore it by just pressing alt-tab, similar to when I alt-tab without minimizing.

What is a reasonable way to achieve this?

The primary use case I have for this is chat apps. People are often talking to me, but I'm also working. I want to "minimize" the chat app so that I don't see it, but I want to be able to alt-tab back to it without having to search for it at the end of the list. I can sometimes use `Alt-Space`, search for it, and find it in the windows, but this doesn't always seem to work (and it's not as embedded in my muscle memory).

I'm fairly open to alternative solutions. An alternative alt-tab interface, more similar to Mac/Windows (centered icons) would also be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the [needed patch to Kwin](https://github.com/Intika-Linux-KDE/kwin-classic-ctrl-tab-switcher/commit/47d6ab59eb8914ddb0857382f2d42dff8bb11402) to achieve this, build your version then use `/usr/local/bin/kwin_x11 --replace` to test it.

```
From 47d6ab59eb8914ddb0857382f2d42dff8bb11402 Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
From: intika <intika@librefox.org>
Date: Tue, 5 May 2020 09:40:08 +0200
Subject: [PATCH] Patch behavior of ctrl+tab to act like mac and windows

---
 focuschain.cpp | 20 ++++++++++----------
 1 file changed, 10 insertions(+), 10 deletions(-)

diff --git a/focuschain.cpp b/focuschain.cpp
index 229314968..b3912fba7 100644
--- a/focuschain.cpp
+++ b/focuschain.cpp
@@ -238,17 +238,17 @@ AbstractClient *FocusChain::nextForDesktop(AbstractClient *reference, uint deskt
 void FocusChain::makeFirstInChain(AbstractClient *client, Chain &chain)
 {
     chain.removeAll(client);
-    if (client->isMinimized()) { // add it before the first minimized ...
-        for (int i = chain.count()-1; i >= 0; --i) {
-            if (chain.at(i)->isMinimized()) {
-                chain.insert(i+1, client);
-                return;
-            }
-        }
-        chain.prepend(client); // ... or at end of chain
-    } else {
+//    if (client->isMinimized()) { // add it before the first minimized ...
+//        for (int i = chain.count()-1; i >= 0; --i) {
+//            if (chain.at(i)->isMinimized()) {
+//                chain.insert(i+1, client);
+//                return;
+//            }
+//        }
+//        chain.prepend(client); // ... or at end of chain
+//    } else {
         chain.append(client);
-    }
+//    }
 }
 
 void FocusChain::makeLastInChain(AbstractClient *client, Chain &chain)
```

Comment: Does this mean that there is no "normal" way of achieving this behaviour, by changing some setting or configuration file? I'm reasonably sure that earlier versions of Plasma were not putting minimized windows in the least-comfortable spot in the switching order (not just at the wrong end, which I could at least reach directly using alt+ctrl+tab)